# Нужна помощь с рефакторингом кода. Данный код у меня в 8ми активити. Помогите пжл. Заранее благодарен

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, рефакторинг, android-webview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initWeb();
    initProgressBar();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void initProgressBar() {
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> pb.setVisibility(View.GONE), 1000);
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void initWeb() {
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Comment: может не оптимизация, а рефакторинг?

Comment: Наверное вы правы. А помочь можете?

Comment: Выносите этот код в базовый класс и от него наследуете все восемь. Единственное **НО** - зачем вам вообще восемь `Activity`, если код в них одинаковый? Не проще обойтись одной, передав при запуске какой-то  отличительный параметр?

Comment: я так делал, но в итоге всегда: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ну так надо разобраться с этой ошибкой. Покажите как вы делали: код базового класса, код наследника, на какую строку указывает ошибка и лог самой ошибки. Пока вы не поймёте причину ошибки - вы будете наступать на эти грабли постоянно, потому что в большинстве случаев `NullPointerException` - это грабли, подложенные самому себе.

Comment: мне нужны все 8 активити, у каждой своя цель, но у них есть общий повторяющийся код. Пытался создать базовое активити, но все время ошибка NullPointerException

Comment: NullPointerException чего именно?(покажите ошибку) простая проверка на null не помогает?